# current state on hashtag scrollto link

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, html-lists, hashtag

I would like to accomplish a color change on a background of a link in a list. The links in the list are in a sticky menu sidebar and will scroll to a certain section on the same page.  When clicked on one link it should change color according the position on the page.

Who can help me with this?

the current HTML is as followed:

```
<div class="widget widget_nav_menu">
    <div class="menu-wij-zijn-umbrella-container">
        <ul id="menu-wij-zijn-umbrella" class="menu">
            <li id="menu-item-970" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-970"><a href="#team">TEAM</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-971" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-971"><a href="#2016">2016</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-972" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-972"><a href="#2015">2015</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-973" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-973"><a href="#2014">2014</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-974" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-974"><a href="#2013">2013</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

you can see it live at: https://wijzijnumbrella.nl/over-umbrella/

Somehow I think I need a script that adds the class current to the appropriate link so I can use the following css style

```
#menu-wij-zijn-umbrella li a.current{background:#d2c153; color:white;}
```

Answer (score 0):

In css just add

`:active` to the `a` tag, and add your background color. You can also add `:hover`.

Also look into bootstrap `scroll-spy`

Comment: I already accomplished the hover state.. as you can see on the provided link. The thing is that I want the background to stay active when for example you click on 2014, and then scrolls to that section and then the background stays active to let you know where you are on the page.  It should highlight it so to say.

Comment: Look at bootstrap, its easier than custom coding it

Comment: It is'nt really an :active state.  it should be a current state.. Just like the main menu on top. When on a certain point on the page, the appropriate link in the sticky bar should hightlight where you are on the page and have the background color stay there ( same color as the hover state)

Comment: :active is css not a class

Comment: Use bootstrap, it had all this included

Comment: Actually I think it should be done with a small script that adds the class current to the appropriate link ( just like on the top menu) so i can add this css #menu-wij-zijn-umbrella li a.current{background:#d2c153; color:white;}

Comment: That would also work, but it is beyond my knowledge, hence bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

In the instances of the demo you provided the values are hardcoded in CSS. Easiest thing would be to use variables in CSS or SCSS to define colors for each section and then use that same variable to define the color of the menu item.

Alternatively you could use javascript to find an element in the section you are looking for and get the color of the text, then use that value to set the color of your menu item. A for loop could do this pretty easily.